# How to add and modify a column in SQL that is specific to the table

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
Name    ReportsTo   Position
-----------------------------
Jill    null        manager
Nathan  Jill        junior
```

I want to add another column in the end that says the title of the person they report to so it would look like this.

```
Name    ReportsTo   Position  Boss
-------------------------------------
Jill    null        manager   none
Nathan  Jill        junior    manager
```

My current code is (to get the first table I displayed)

```
SELECT 
    t1.Name, t1.ReportsTo, t1.Position 
FROM 
    yourTable t1 
WHERE 
    ReportsTo = 'Jill' OR ReportsTo IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

To bring in the immediate managers of each employee you may use a self join:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name, t1.ReportsTo, t1.Position, COALESCE(t2.Position, 'none') AS Boss
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.Name = t1.ReportsTo;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks. So I forgot to add my code in the post. My code is currently ```SELECT t1.Name, t1.ReportsTo, t1.Position FROM yourTable t1 WHERE ReportsTo = 'Jill' or ReportsTo  IS null``` how would I add your code onto my code?

Comment: This is the code I used to obtain the table I displayed

Comment: Add `WHERE t1.ReportsTo = 'Jill' OR t1.ReportsTo IS NULL` to the end of my answer.  [See the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a18e9e87eb8299cabbf8dfeef507aa0).